# How can I find an approximate solution to this integral?

Tags: laplace-method

I am stuck in integrating the following integral 
$I(x) = \int_{a}^{b}t^{2}e^{-xf(t)}\,dt$
where $f(t)=(1-e^{-t})^2$. The main problem here is at the point where $f(t)$ is zero, $t^2$ is zero. I am not sure how to evaluate this integral.  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You will need higher order terms from the Laplace approximation. See the last section here: https://www.math.unl.edu/~scohn1/8423/intasym1.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I will check the file.

Comment: To make sure. 0 is interior to the bounds a and b?

Comment: No. In fact I need to integrate from zero to an arbitrary upper limit

Comment: You can have a problem because $f(t)$ tends to a finite limit as $t\to +\infty$. You can only look at finite intervals and for larger upper limits of integration you will need larger and larger values of $x$ to keep the contribution of the tail small.